# how to run appmaster.jar in yarn

Tags: maven, hadoop, jar, hadoop-yarn, resourcemanager

I want to run some application which is killed or finished (not running application).

I run application like this :

```
$ yarn jar /usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/hadoop-yarn-applications-distributedshell-2.7.2.jar -jar /usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/hadoop-yarn-applications-distributedshell-2.7.2.jar -queue queueTEST01 -shell_command "vmstat 60" -container_memory 2048
```

and figure out that it saves two files in hdfs.

```
***
[root@em-name01 logs]# hadoop fs -ls 

-rw-r--r--   3 hadoop supergroup 45579 2016-11-02 11:03 /user/hadoop/DistributedShell/application_1478051489888_0004/AppMaster.jar

-rwx--x---   3 hadoop supergroup         79 2016-11-02 11:03 /user/hadoop/DistributedShell/application_1478051489888_0004/shellCommands
```

---

If the application killed or finished, how can I run the AppMaster.jar again???

Or is here some other way?